# iOS app with subscription on remote server

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

First of all, I'm uncertain if this is a question for AskDifferent. If not, please point me to the correct section.

I have a website that features paid subscription based content. I would like to create an iOS app in which users login and have access to the app's functionality only if their subscription on the website is valid.

Is this something that is allowed as per Apples app guidelines? I've heard rumors that it's not, but wasn't able to find anything regarding this specific scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is allowed. However you are required to let users sign up through the iOS app. You get 85% and Apple gets 15%.

> **3.1.3 Content-based “Reader” Apps**
>
> Apps may allow a user to access previously purchased content or content subscriptions (specifically:
> magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video, access to
> professional databases, VoIP, cloud storage, and approved services
> such as educational apps that manage student grades and schedules),
> provided the app does not direct users to a purchasing mechanism other
> than IAP.
>
> **3.1.4 Content Codes**
>
> Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR codes, etc. In limited circumstances, such as when features are dependent upon specific hardware to function, the app may unlock that functionality without using in-app purchase (e.g. an astronomy app that adds features when synced with a telescope).

Source: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#content-based-reader-apps

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Lets say I don't want to use IAP. That means that the app would be approved as long as I don't explicitly ask people to sign up for the content on my website (even if that is the only way to get the content)?

Comment: Yes, example: Spotify is doing that. You cannot subscribe to Spotify Premium inside the app. But you cannot mention a premium subscription in anyway inside the app.